# Devise Invitable optional custom message

Tags: devise

I would like to add an optional text_field to add an optional message to the invitation email. So if nothing put into the message then the standard message from invitation_instructions.html.erb should be send otherwise the message of the text_field.

How to do this in devise?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To accomplish this you can use your own mailer instead of having devise email things for you.

Here is how to do it:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_reader :raw_invitation_token
end

class InvitationsController < Devise::InvitationsController
  def create
    @from    = params[:from]
    @subject = params[:invite_subject]
    @content = params[:invite_content]

    @user = User.invite!(params[:user], current_user) do |u|
      u.skip_invitation = true
    end

    @user.deliver_invitation
    email = NotificationMailer.invite_message(@user, @from, @subject, @content)
  end
end

class NotificationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def invite_message(user, venue, from, subject, content)
    @user = user
    @token = user.raw_invitation_token
    invitation_link = accept_user_invitation_url(:invitation_token => @token)

    mail(:from => from, :bcc => from, :to => @user.email, :subject => subject) do |format|
      content = content.gsub '{{first_name}}', user.first_name
      content = content.gsub '{{last_name}}', user.first_name
      content = content.gsub '{{full_name}}', user.full_name
      content = content.gsub('{{invitation_link}}', invitation_link)
      format.text do
        render :text => content
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The `raw_invitation_token` only exists in newer versions of devise_invitable (compatible with devise >= 3.1).

We are essentially skipping the devise invitation process all together and using our own mailer. We take the content as a parameter and send it as the body of the email. We even substitute placeholders with their actual values.

This solution will give you a lot of flexibility to whatever you want with emails. You can even add a tracking pixel to it if you would like.

Comment: I would like to send an custom invitation reminder with the same link three days later. With the prior devise 3.1 version that was no problem at all. But as far as I see it I now have to either generate a new token and a new link for the reminder (which I don't want) or store the raw_invitation_token away for later use (which defies the whole idea of the new token system). Any ideas how to solve this dilemma?